# How to update the previous properties of state after onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

So I want to update the previous properties of my state with array of objects.Initially I made only two objects.I want to implement bookmark functionality in my moviedb app.When I click on the icon it should change color as well as change the value of `isFavorited` property in my `useState`.

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState({
        favorited: false,
        customColor: "white"
    });


const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive({ ...isActive, !favorited});
    if(isActive.favorited){
        setActive( {...isActive, customColor: "red"});
    }else{
        setActive( {...isActive, customColor: "white"});
    }
}
```

I am calling the `handleToggle` function on clicking a icon.How to make it so that the value of favorited toggles everytime I click it using `useState`?I get a error squiggle on `!favorited`

Answer (score 1):

Writing `{...isActive, !favorited}` is not a valid JS syntax.

Try rewriting the function to:

```
const handleToggle = () => {
  setActive((prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      favorited: !prevState.favorited,
      customColor: prevState.favorited ? "red" : "white",
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: While it solves my problem,how to set that ```customColor``` in ```<BsFillBookmarkFill className="bookmark" size={34} onClick={handleToggle} color={this.isActive.customColor} />``` ?

Comment: Please just ask a separate question with provided context to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the state by using the prevState :-

```
 setActive((prevState) => ({
       ...prevState, favorited : !favorited}
    ));
```